# i have to sum the numbers like sum of 55555 is 25 and sum 0f 25 is 7 ,but we have to use while loop specifically to solve it?

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, sum

**I have to sum the numbers like sum of 55555 is 25 and sum of 25 is 7, but we have to use while loop specifically to solve it**

```
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
    string = membershipId.split('');                
    let sum = 0;                               
    for (var i = 0; i \< string.length; i++) {  
        sum += parseInt(string\[i\],10);         
    }
    return sum \>= 10 ? createCheckDigit(String(sum)) : sum;
}
console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"));
```

Now i have to do this using while loop. The final answer of the code will be 7 if the number is 55555.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. All your teacher or colleagues if you are stuck. Also show is what you tried if you ask a question.

Comment: Why would `55555` result in `7`? In top description you said it would be `25`.

Comment: Please fix the invalid `\<`, `\[`, `\]` and `\>`. Not sure how that got in there, or why, but please improve it by [edit]-ing the question. Make sure that the code at least compiles, or even better: consider using a ["Stack Snippet"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do),

Comment: the sum of 55555 is 25 and then we have sum it further until i gets converted into a single digit @user3783243

Comment: Oh, so `55555 is 25 and sum of 25 is 7`, is the full example, not 2 different examples.

Comment: i am very new here and everyone is not lucky as you to have teachers and colleagues or a friend arround but thanks for your opinion.@cloned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation (strings can be iterated like arrays)

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  membershipId = String(membershipId)
  let sum = i = 0

  while (i < membershipId.length) {
    sum += Number(membershipId[i++])
  }

  return (sum >= 10) ? createCheckDigit(sum) : sum
}

console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"))
console.log(createCheckDigit(77777))
```

Answer (score -1):

To find the digital root of a number, you need to repeatedly sum its digits until it reachs a single-digit number

```
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  let sum = membershipId;
  while (sum >= 10) {
    let digits = sum.toString().split('');
    sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(digits[i]);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"))
```

Comment: let sum = membershipId;